# Creating private object instances for use within System.Threading.Tasks.Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

Let's say I have a business object that is very expensive to instantiate, and I would never want to create more than say 10 instances of that object in my application.  So, that would mean I would never want to have more than 10 concurrent worker threads running at one time.

I'd like to use the new System.Threading.Tasks to create a task like this:

```
 var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myPrivateObject.DoSomethingProductive());
```

Is there a sample out there that would show how to:

1. create an 'object pool' for use by the TaskFactory?
2. limit the TaskFactory to a specified number of threads?
3. lock an instance in the object pool so it can only be used by one task at a time?

---

Igby's answer led me to this [excellent blog post](http://www.codethinked.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection) from Justin Etheridge.  which then prompted me to write this sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyThreadedApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // build a list of 10 expensive working object instances
            var expensiveStuff = new BlockingCollection<ExpensiveWorkObject>();
            for (int i = 65; i < 75; i++)
            {
                expensiveStuff.Add(new ExpensiveWorkObject(Convert.ToChar(i)));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} expensive objects created", expensiveStuff.Count);
            // build a list of work to be performed
            Random r = new Random();
            var work = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                work.Enqueue(r.Next(10000));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} items in work queue", work.Count);
            // process the list of work items in fifteen threads
            for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var expensiveThing = expensiveStuff.Take();
                        try
                        {
                            int workValue;
                            if (work.TryDequeue(out workValue))
                            {
                                expensiveThing.DoWork(workValue);
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            expensiveStuff.Add(expensiveThing);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

class ExpensiveWorkObject
{
    char identity;

    public void DoWork(int someDelay)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(someDelay);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", identity, someDelay);
    }

    public ExpensiveWorkObject(char Identifier)
    {
        identity = Identifier;
    }
}
```

So, I'm using the BlockingCollection as an object pool, and the worker threads don't check the queue for available work until they have an exclusive control over one of the expensive object instances.  I *think* this meets my requirements, but I would really like feedback from people who know this stuff better than I do...

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't realize I was stupid.

Comment: Who said anything about you being stupid?

Comment: I've been working through the examples found in the Parallel Extensions Samples (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=165717).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two thoughts:

*Limited Concurrency Scheduler*

You can use a custom task scheduler which limits the number of concurrent tasks. Internally it will allocate up to **n** Task instances. If you pass it more tasks than it has available instances, it will put them in a queue. Adding custom schedulers like this is a design feature of the TPL.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) is a good example of such a scheduler. I have sucessfully used a modified version of this.

*Object Pool*

Another option is to use an object pool. It's a very similar concept except that instead of putting the limitation at the task level, you put it on the number of object instances, and force tasks to wait for a free instance to become available. This has the benefit of reducing the overhead of object creation, but you need to ensure the object is written in a way that allows instances of it to be recycled. You could create an object pool around a concurrent producer-consumer collection such as [ConcurrentStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx) where the consumer adds the instance back to the collection when it's finished.

Comment: +1 I would use a BlockingCollection so that thread/s attempting to issue tasks when the pool is empty are forced to wait until tasks are returned to the pool.  A continuation could do the recycling.

Comment: @Martin James, would a continuation be 'more fail-safe' (or better coding practice) than using the try/finally in my sample above?

Comment: @DavidMontgomery - no, try/finally is fine.